# The math behind the time complexity of Heap Insertion

Tags: time-complexity

Insertion into a heap is an O(logn) operation. Insertion of n elements into a heap one by one is summarised as O(n * logn). I wonder about the math behind this, because I could not reach to the same outcome.

Let's say we have an empty heap h = [].

- The first insertion will be a constant time operation, say O(1)
- The second insertion will also be O(1), because there was only one element in the heap
- The third will be O(log2) and so on

So if we write it down, the overall time complexity will be:

O(1 + 1 + log2 + log3 + ... + log(n-1))
= O(2 + log(n - 1)!)
= O(logn!) approximately, which is nowhere close to O(n * logn).

Comment: It is [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) or you can write $\leq n \cdot \log n$ directly.

Comment: "which is nowhere close": what ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\ln(n!)=\ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^nk\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(k)\approx\int_{k=0}^n\ln(t)\,dt=(t\ln(t)-t)\Big|_{t=0}^n=n\ln(n)-n.$$

One can show that the approximation error does not impact the asymptotic behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the formula, now I see it.